# Javascript replace not removing quotes from array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove quotes from an array

So this is what I'm trying:

```
array = ['cars', 'dogs'];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = array[i].replace(/''/g, "");
}

console.log(array);
```

OUTPUT:

```
['cars', 'dogs']
```

What I need is this output:

```
[cars, dogs]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. Are you trying to turn your strings into variable names?

Comment: There are no quote characters in your strings. Also your regex will only replace sequences of *two* quote characters.

Comment: I think you have some fundamental misunderstandings of javascript

Comment: You're confused. There are no quotes in the array; the quotes you see are feaured in console.log output to denote that the elements in the array are strings. They're not actually part of the values.

Comment: The quotes denote that it is a string in the console....

Comment: The `'`'s in `'cat'` indicates that it's a string literal. i.e. it's part of the language's syntax, not part of the value stored in `array`, in the same way that `[` and `]` indicate an array literal and the `,` separates two items, but they aren't actually *part of* the array. The console output is just showing similar syntax so you can understand what type of value was logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log("[ " + array.join(", ") + "] ")
```

array.join will create a new string that is formed by concatenating all the values in the array with a specified string between them.

Comment: `console.log(\`[${array}]\`)` would achieve the same effect, but I don't think that actually clears up OP's confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There are no quotes in that array.

`array[0]` as a string values of `cars`. The quotes just means its a string.
if you print it out to the console or page, there are no quotes.

Comment: Well the console might show quotes for clarity. You're right of course.